# Avoid Firestore permission error without using first operator

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a subscription method like so and it is working fine.

```
 setOnboardingUser(uid: string): void {
    this.currentUserUid = uid;

    combineLatest([this.getProfile(uid), this.getUserFirstName(uid), this.getUserLastName(uid)]))
      .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
        this.OnboardingUser = res1;
        this.userFirstName = res2.firstName;
        this.userLastName = res3.lastName;
      }, err => { console.log(err); }); // it throws error here when signout
  }
```

But when the user logged out it shows Firestore permission errors. i.e. I have rules on Firestore

I can avoid it if I use `first()` operator like so. But since I need a continuous update of the UI I cannot use `first()`. Can you tell me how to do that? i.e. avoid rules permission errors when sign out?

```
 setOnboardingUser(uid: string): void {
    this.currentUserUid = uid;

    combineLatest([this.getProfile(uid), this.getUserFirstName(uid), this.getUserLastName(uid)]).pipe(first())
      .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
        this.OnboardingUser = res1;
        this.userFirstName = res2.firstName;
        this.userLastName = res3.lastName;
      }, err => { console.log(err); });
  }
```

Permission error:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:101053:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:116278:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:116791:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:112588:43)
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:112517:30
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:112557:28
    at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:102396:20
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3594:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:71855:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:3593:52)
```

*signOut*

```
 async signOut(): Promise<void> {
     return await this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing the minimal security rules that throw the permission denied, it'll be hard to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you think is that possible to solve this issue by adjusting the rules? I assume it is not possible since it shows that error due to the above Subscription. Your thoughts?

Comment: P.S. My backend developer does the Rule changes. It has a lot. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it will be hard to help without seeing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using `unsubscribe()`.

```
 private onboardingUserSubscription: Subscription;


setOnboardingUser(uid: string): void {
    this.currentUserUid = uid;

    this.onboardingUserSubscription = combineLatest([this.getProfile(uid), this.getUserFirstName(uid), this.getUserLastName(uid)]).pipe(first())
      .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
        this.OnboardingUser = res1;
        this.userFirstName = res2.firstName;
        this.userLastName = res3.lastName;
      }, err => { console.log(err); });
  }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.onboardingUserSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```